# How to prevent editing React.js code on production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authorization

I'm rather new to front-end development and I'm currently developing an application using React.js as front-end and ASP.NET Core as an API back-end.

I'm currently in the process of developing a granular authorization system which depends on the claims of the user that exist in the JWT stored in the local storage, if the claim exist, then an element will be rendered, otherwise, it will not. Pretty standard.

```
static getUserInfo = () => {
    return JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem("jWT").split(".")[1]));
  };

  static isAuthorized(claim) {
    let claims = this.getUserInfo().claims;
    if (claims.includes(claim) || claims === "GLOBAL_ADMIN") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Since this code does not call an API to check if the user actually has this claim or not, can an attacker just opens chrome developer tools and modifies the code so that it will be like:

```
  static isAuthorized(claim) {
    let claims = this.getUserInfo().claims;
    if (claims.includes(claim) || claims === "GLOBAL_ADMIN" || true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And get access to the whole system? I was able to do the above in development environment with source maps available but could not in production because the build does not include source maps, I was able to modify the code but changes did not take effect.

My exact question is, can you modify React.js code directly in the browser and have its effect immediately as the user does his next action?

Comment: Use node.js then. Client side code is not safer anyhow.

Comment: If modifying client code gives a user full access to your system, that's not an issue with the client, it's an issue with the server. The server should never blindly trust that the client is telling the truth.

Comment: It's worth noting though - JWTs contain a signed checksum that verifies that the contents has not been modified. If your server is validating JWTs correctly, you should be safe from users editing token claims.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for a determined malicious actor to do nearly anything with the client-side code. That's why you can't have your app rely on client-side checks. Client-side checks are just for UI purposes, nothing more.

> ...And get access to the whole system?

Not if the system is correctly designed, e.g., with server-side checks. Information the user shouldn't have access to should never be sent to their browser (in code, HTML, data files, etc.). That is, you never send them information they shouldn't see, then prevent them seeing it with a client-side check; instead, you just don't send them the information they shouldn't see. That way, it doesn't matter what they do with the client-side code, it's not going to get them anything.

Similarly, every command sent to the server to do something needs to be verified on the server as coming from an authenticated user with appropriate permissions to take that action.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I currently understand (which is most likely wrong), what should prevent a malicious - authenticated- user from calling the authorization API after he has modified the code that sends the request so that even if the request fails, they will still get the result of an authorized call?

Example:

Modify the (then) and (catch) callback of an Axios post to both return the authorized result of the call? Or modify any condition that might be present in them into their favor?

Comment: @Aboody - You authenticate them *on the server*. If they send you a request for an action they're not allowed to perform, you deny them that action.

Comment: @Crowder - Yes, I understand, but the user will modify the code so that the denied response will be in his favor! I'm using React.js, I return simple HTTP responses, I don't return HTML that does not include what he should see or what he shouldn't.

Comment: @Aboody - It's impossible for the user to change what he/she doesn't have. Your **server** must ensure that it never sends anything to the user they shouldn't have. The server's check on the user can't be based on anything the user can manipulate. Modifying your client-side code can't change that, because it's your **server** that's doing it.

Comment: @Crowder - Since I'm using React.js, I'm sending the the whole front-end application as a JavaScript file in (main.something.js) which can be edited directly. The API calls are in this file. Thank you for replying so far.

Comment: @Aboody - That's just code. What matters is information. Presumably the **code** doesn't contain information the user shouldn't see, it just contains code to show information you'll get from the server.